# Paging & sorting & filtering to razor page scaffolding automatic

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, scaffold, blazor

Can we scaffold an entity for making razor pages with paging & sorting & filtering features automatically without writing code for these features both back end and front end codes like third party's controls (grid) in asp.net webform or asp.net mvc?

Is there any package for that in razor page or in blazor?

at least how can we customize razor page scaffolding?

or which third party's grid control do you recommend for asp.net core and razor pages or blazor?

(I have vs code and .net core 3)

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't right now do such scaffolding with Razor Components. The new framework is only in its early development stage.

The concept of razor page does not exist in Blazor (Razor Components). You may say Razor Component, which can act as a page if you add to it a @page directive, or a child component if you omit the @page directive, but "**Razor Page(s) is a new aspect of ASP.NET Core MVC that makes coding page-focused scenarios easier and more productive**"

Language can be the source of misunderstanding, and I had to read your post twice in order to under it.

I believe that Telerik is right now frantically creating grid control to work in Blazor. See here: https://www.telerik.com/blogs/introducing-the-telerik-ui-for-blazor-early-preview

As far as I remember, there are some samples made by the community... look for it in the Blazor web site. But why won't you develop it yourself. This is the best way to learn Razor Components.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thank you. the best practice for display large data and many entity and data entry for us is show a table or grid with full features like paging & sorting & filtering. We did it in asp.net webform and devexpress aspxgridview. We want that easy strategy(grid) for asp.net core and use of ease razor pages instead of mvc. after search we realized that asp.net core razor pages or blazor have not customize scaffolding or there is not any package for make paging&sorting&filtering automatically. (https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/issues/11296). So your solution is good I think : Telerik UI for Blazor

Comment: Is Telerik UI for Blazor free?

Comment: @mammadkoma, If you are looking for a grid feature closer than you use on webforms, you can take a look to [Blazor.FlexGrid](https://github.com/Mewriick/Blazor.FlexGrid). Also, I vote to close your question because it is off-topic.

Comment: Telerik is not free. But you can get a trial. 

Also, have a look at MatBlazor: https://www.matblazor.com/, they offer some free components which can do mostly what Telerik can do...